# How to animate shadow with gradient?

Tags: swift, animation, gradient, shadow

I have a chart like below:

[image]

I have a problem with animation and shadows.
i draw a gradient with animation but from the beginning i have the shadow and mask layer which i don't want, i want the shadow animating with the gradient.
the current chart with animation is like below.
[image]

i dont want the user see the shadow and mask layer from the beginning.

here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CircularProgressView: UIView {

@IBInspectable var containerCircleColor: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray
@IBInspectable var gradientStartColor: UIColor = UIColor.green
@IBInspectable var gradientEndColor: UIColor = UIColor.yellow
@IBInspectable var arcWidth: CGFloat = 20


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    circularProgressView_init()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    circularProgressView_init()
}


fileprivate func circularProgressView_init() {

    let viewHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(viewHeight)

}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    circularProgressView_init()
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let width = self.bounds.width
    let center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX, y: self.bounds.midY)
    let radius: CGFloat = (width - (arcWidth * 2.5)) / 2
    let progressStartAngle: CGFloat = 3 * CGFloat.pi / 2
    let progressEndAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat.pi / 2

    //fill circular
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter:  center,
                                  radius: radius,
                                  startAngle: 0,
                                  endAngle: 360,
                                  clockwise: true)
    circlePath.lineWidth = arcWidth
    containerCircleColor.setStroke()
    circlePath.stroke()


    //MARK: ProgressPath
    let progressPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                    radius: radius,
                                    startAngle: progressStartAngle,
                                    endAngle: progressEndAngle,
                                    clockwise: true)
    progressPath.lineWidth = arcWidth
    progressPath.lineCapStyle = .round

    //MARK: Gradient
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [gradientStartColor.cgColor , gradientEndColor.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1, y:1)
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds

    //MARK: Animation
    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    anim.duration = 2
    anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    anim.fromValue = 0
    anim.toValue = 1

    //MARK: Mask Layer
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = progressPath.cgPath
    maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    maskLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    maskLayer.lineWidth = arcWidth
    maskLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

    gradientLayer.mask = maskLayer

    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let shadow = UIColor.lightGray
    let shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3.1, height: 3.1)
    let shadowBlurRadius: CGFloat = 5
    context!.saveGState()
    context!.setShadow(offset: shadowOffset, blur: shadowBlurRadius,  color: (shadow as UIColor).cgColor)
    progressPath.stroke()
    context?.restoreGState()

    maskLayer.add(anim, forKey: nil)
    gradientLayer.add(anim, forKey: nil)

  }
}
```

Is it possible at all?
If it is not, how can i at least hide the shadow and mask and show it after animation ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create another layer to give the shadow.

1 - first you have to create a UIView as a `shadowLayer`

2 - then mask this `shadowLayer` with the path and layer same as the `maskLayer`(in your code) you have already created. e.g: `shadowMaskLayer`

3 - add the shadow properties to this new `shadowMaskLayer`

4 - then add the `shadowLayer` to the original UIView `CircularProgressView`

5 - also add the animation you already have to this `shadowLayer` to animate the shadow with the whole circle.

Don't hesitate to ask questions ;)

Comment: thanks, that's a good idea. i will change my code and share the result.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i put the correct answer here, maybe some one need it in the future.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CircularProgressView: UIView {

@IBInspectable var containerCircleColor: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray
@IBInspectable var gradientStartColor: UIColor = UIColor.yellow
@IBInspectable var gradientEndColor: UIColor = UIColor.red
@IBInspectable var arcWidth: CGFloat = 20
@IBInspectable var progressPercent: CGFloat = 50

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    circularProgressView_init()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    circularProgressView_init()
}

fileprivate func circularProgressView_init() {
    let viewHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(viewHeight)
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    circularProgressView_init()
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let width = self.bounds.width
    let center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX, y: self.bounds.midY)
    let radius: CGFloat = (width - (arcWidth * 2.5)) / 2
    let progressStartAngle: CGFloat = 3 * CGFloat.pi / 2
    let progressEndAngle: CGFloat = ConvertToTrigonometry.shared.trigonimetryCordinate(percentage: progressPercent) //CGFloat.pi / 2

    //fill circular
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter:  center,
                                  radius: radius,
                                  startAngle: 0,
                                  endAngle: 360,
                                  clockwise: true)
    circlePath.lineWidth = arcWidth
    containerCircleColor.setStroke()
    circlePath.stroke()


    //MARK: ProgressPath
    let progressPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                    radius: radius,
                                    startAngle: progressStartAngle,
                                    endAngle: progressEndAngle,
                                    clockwise: true)
    progressPath.lineWidth = arcWidth
    progressPath.lineCapStyle = .round

    //MARK: Gradient
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [gradientStartColor.cgColor , gradientEndColor.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1, y:1)
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds

    //MARK: Mask Layer
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = progressPath.cgPath
    maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    maskLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    maskLayer.lineWidth = arcWidth
    maskLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    maskLayer.masksToBounds = false

    gradientLayer.mask = maskLayer

    //MARK: Shadow
    let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shadowLayer.frame = bounds
    shadowLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    layer.addSublayer(shadowLayer)

    let maskShadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskShadowLayer.path = progressPath.cgPath
    maskShadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    maskShadowLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    maskShadowLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    maskShadowLayer.lineWidth = arcWidth
    maskShadowLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    maskShadowLayer.masksToBounds = false
    maskShadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    maskShadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    maskShadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3.1, height: 3.1)

    shadowLayer.mask = maskShadowLayer

    //MARK: Animation
    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    anim.duration = 2
    anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    anim.fromValue = 0
    anim.toValue = 1

    maskShadowLayer.add(anim, forKey: nil)
    maskLayer.add(anim, forKey: nil)
    gradientLayer.add(anim, forKey: nil)

    layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

 }

}
```

And also a helper class which i use for trigonometry conversion:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ConvertToTrigonometry {

static let shared = ConvertToTrigonometry()

func trigonimetryCordinate(percentage: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let pi = CGFloat.pi
    let trigonometryRatio = (percentage * 360) / 100 // How much you want to move forward in axis.
    let endPointDegree = (3 * pi / 2) + ((trigonometryRatio * 2 / 360) * pi) // End point on axis based on your trigonometryRatio and the start point which is 3pi/2
    return endPointDegree
 }
}
```

this solution draw an arc with animating gradient and shadow.
you can find the complete project in my [Github](https://github.com/MinaAshena/MACircularChart).